# minidlna ‘PIX_FMT_RGB32_1’ undeclared error with libavutil

Tags: raspbian-jessie, ffmpeg, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to compile the latest miniDLNA code from https://github.com/folhabranca/minidlna on raspbian jessie (8) 
I installed `libavutils` and `libavutils-dev` from respositories
But when I `make` I get:

```
video_thumb.c: In function ‘video_thumb_generate_mta_file’:
video_thumb.c:465:73: error: ‘PIX_FMT_RGB32_1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    res = video_thumb_generate_ctx_tobuff(fctx, &img, per[i], MTA_WIDTH, PIX_FMT_RGB32_1);
                                                                         ^
Makefile:600: recipe for target 'video_thumb.o' failed
make[2]: *** [video_thumb.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/minidlna'
Makefile:622: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/minidlna'
Makefile:446: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the problem?
How Can I compile miniDLNA in raspbian?

**UPDATE:**
I just tried to upgrade to lasted debian version (buster) and tried again.
Now it seems libraries are too new !
and I get:

```
video_thumb.c: In function ‘video_thumb_generate_mta_file’:
video_thumb.c:464:73: error: ‘PIX_FMT_RGB32_1’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32_1’?
    res = video_thumb_generate_ctx_tobuff(fctx, &img, per[i], MTA_WIDTH, PIX_FMT_RGB32_1);
                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                         AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32_1
```

I tried to add AV_ prefix to these macros and now I have:

```
/usr/bin/ld: video_thumb.o: in function `video_thumb_generate_ctx_tobuff':
video_thumb.c:255: undefined reference to `avpicture_deinterlace'
```

Which library provides `avpicture_deinterlace`?

Comment: In the meantime *jessie* is old-old-stable. I would use the up to date version *buster*.

Comment: @Ingo: I just upgraded to `buster` but unfortunately it still doesnt match ! now I get   `error: ‘PIX_FMT_RGB32_1’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32_1’`; do you know which exact version of libavutil matches minidlna?

Comment: Please correct that information and the tag in your question. You can edit the question. I haven't compiled miniDLNA jet, so I cannot help much. But maybe you will find someone else if you provide an updated question ;-)